# How do you loop through an array to display images with a setInterval ES5

Tags: javascript, dom, setinterval, ecmascript-5

So, I created a Carousel to loop through images with a setInterval at 3000. I hard coded these with if statements to update icons at below the image as well (I'll put in 2 links for screenshots.)

I'm trying to figure out how to code this with a loop to update the src attribute of my image element.

Variables:

```
var $rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right-arrow-icon');
var $leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left-arrow-icon');
var $img = document.querySelector('#image-source');
var $circleOne = document.querySelector('#circle-one');
var $circleTwo = document.querySelector('#circle-two');
var $circleThree = document.querySelector('#circle-three');
var $circleFour = document.querySelector('#circle-four');
var $circleFive = document.querySelector('#circle-five');
```

My current code to do the job which I want to be able to loop through an array:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(rightClick, 3000);

$rightArrow.addEventListener('click', rightClick);

function rightClick(event) {
  if ($img.getAttribute('src') === 'images/001.png') {
    $img.setAttribute('src', 'images/004.png');
    $circleOne.setAttribute('class', 'far fa-circle');
    $circleTwo.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-circle');
  } else if ($img.getAttribute('src') === 'images/004.png') {
    $img.setAttribute('src', 'images/007.png');
    $circleTwo.setAttribute('class', 'far fa-circle');
    $circleThree.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-circle');
  } else if ($img.getAttribute('src') === 'images/007.png') {
    $img.setAttribute('src', 'images/025.png');
    $circleThree.setAttribute('class', 'far fa-circle');
    $circleFour.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-circle');
  } else if ($img.getAttribute('src') === 'images/025.png') {
    $img.setAttribute('src', 'images/039.png');
    $circleFour.setAttribute('class', 'far fa-circle');
    $circleFive.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-circle');
  } else if ($img.getAttribute('src') === 'images/039.png') {
    $img.setAttribute('src', 'images/001.png');
    $circleFive.setAttribute('class', 'far fa-circle');
    $circleOne.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-circle');
  }
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  intervalID = setInterval(rightClick, 3000);
}
```

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiwyM.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The biggest clue to where you can see the opportunity for loop is the repetition of codes. If you find yourself writing similar patterns, chances are it could be refactored into cleaner code. This is my solution:

First I put your images into an array as so:

```
const imgArray = [ 'images/001.png','images/004.png', 'images/007.png', 'images/025.png','images/039.png' ]
```

Instead of getting the image string with getAttribute every time, make use of the input variables for the function to make it dynamic:

```
function rightClick(currentImg) {

    const currentImgIndex = imgArray.indexOf(currentImg)

    let nextImgIndex

    //Circle back to 0 if the current index is the last
    if (currentImgIndex == imgArray.length - 1) {
        nextImgIndex = 0
    } else {
        nextImgIndex = currentImgIndex + 1
    }

    // You can make this even cleaner by using ternary operator
    // let nextImgIndex = currentImgIndex == imgArray.length - 1 ? 0 : currentImgIndex + 1 

    $img.setAttribute('src', imgArray[nextImgIndex]);

    // We set up the id for the circles as "circles-1", "circles-2" etc..
    // so that we can make use of the index to make it dynamic

    let $currentCircle = document.querySelector(`#circle-${currentImgIndex + 1}`)
    let $nextCircle = document.querySelector(`#circle-${nextImgIndex + 1}`)
 
    // use classList to remove and add only the necessary class
    $currentCircle.classList.remove('fas')
    $currentCircle.classList.add('far')

    $nextCircle.classList.remove('far')
    $nextCircle.classList.add('fas')

}
```

And finally, use the setInterval to call it like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    let currentImg = $img.getAttribute('src')
    rightClick(currentImg)
}, 3000);
```

I have tested it in CodePen here:
https://codepen.io/isaacyong/pen/GRNzbzG

Let me know if that helps you and if you have further questions feel free to ask!

Comment: First off, thank you very much. This cleared things up very well with excellent explanation as to what you were doing with the code. Thank you, AGAIN, for putting the time into it!

So far, things are looking great! I'm adding functionality to my left arrow and the icons as well.

This works 100% for any other new developers working on a Carousel.

Comment: You’re welcome! Do mark the answer as accepted if it works well for you. All the best!